# Substract shortest string containing all search criteria

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, search

I have a problem to solve where given a string `source` and a collection of search criteria `criteria`, the algorithm has to return the shortest possible substring of `source` that contains all items of `criteria`.

=================================

**UPDATE**

- The same search criteria might be in the source string multiple
  times. In that case, it is required to return the sub-string
  containing the particular instance of the search criteria such that
  it is the shortest among all possible sub-strings.
- The search items can contain spaces in them such as `hello world`
- The order in which the search criteria are found does not matter as long as they are all in the resultant sub-string

==================================

```
String source = "aaa wwwww fgffsd ththththt sss sgsgsgsghs bfbfb hhh sdfg kkk dhdhtrherhrhrthrthrt ddfhdetehehe kkk wdwd aaa vcvc hhh zxzx sss nbnbn";
List<String> criteria = new List<string> { "kkk", "aaa", "sss", "hhh" };
```

The input above should return the following substring: `kkk wdwd aaa vcvc hhh zxzx sss`

Unfortunately, I spent a lot of time trying to write such an algorithm but I couldn't get it just right. Below is the code I have got so far:

```
public struct Extraction
{
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
    public int Length
    {
        get
        {
            var length = this.End - this.Start;
            return length;
        }
    }

    public Extraction(int start, int end)
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }
}

public class TextExtractor
{
    private String _source;
    private Dictionary<String, List<Int32>> _criteriaIndexes;
    private Dictionary<String, int> _entryIndex;

    public TextExtractor(String source, List<String> searchCriteria)
    {
        this._source = source;
        this._criteriaIndexes = this.ExtractIndexes(source, searchCriteria);
        this._entryIndex = _criteriaIndexes.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, v => 0);
    }

    public String Extract()
    {
        List<Extraction> possibleExtractions = new List<Extraction>();

        int index = 0;
        int min = int.MaxValue;
        int max = 0;
        bool shouldStop = false;
        while (index < _criteriaIndexes.Count && !shouldStop)
        {
            Boolean compareWithAll = index == _criteriaIndexes.Count - 1;
            if (!compareWithAll)
            {
                var current = _criteriaIndexes.ElementAt(index);
                this.CalculateMinMax(current, ref min, ref max);
                index++;
            }
            else
            {
                var entry = _criteriaIndexes.Last();
                while (_entryIndex[entry.Key] < entry.Value.Count)
                {
                    int a = min;
                    int b = max;
                    this.CalculateMinMax(entry, ref a, ref b);

                    _entryIndex[entry.Key]++;
                    Extraction ext = new Extraction(a, b);
                    possibleExtractions.Add(ext);
                }
                int k = index - 1;

                while (k >= 0)
                {
                    var prev = _criteriaIndexes.ElementAt(k);
                    if (prev.Value.Count - 1 > _entryIndex[prev.Key])
                    {
                        _entryIndex[prev.Key]++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        k--;
                    }
                }
                shouldStop = _criteriaIndexes.All(x => x.Value.Count - 1 <= _entryIndex[x.Key]);
                _entryIndex[entry.Key] = 0;
                index = 0;
                min = int.MaxValue;
                max = 0;
            }
        }

        Extraction shortest = possibleExtractions.First(x => x.Length.Equals(possibleExtractions.Min(p => p.Length)));
        String result = _source.Substring(shortest.Start, shortest.Length);
        return result;
    }

    private Dictionary<String, List<Int32>> ExtractIndexes(String source, List<String> searchCriteria)
    {
        Dictionary<String, List<Int32>> result = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
        foreach (var criteria in searchCriteria)
        {
            Int32 i = 0;
            Int32 startingIndex = 0;
            var indexes = new List<int>();
            while (i > -1)
            {
                i = source.IndexOf(criteria, startingIndex);
                if (i > -1)
                {
                    startingIndex = i + 1;
                    indexes.Add(i);
                }
            }
            if (indexes.Any())
            {
                result.Add(criteria, indexes);
            }

        }
        return result;
    }

    private void CalculateMinMax(KeyValuePair<String, List<int>> current, ref int min, ref int max)
    {
        int j = current.Value[_entryIndex[current.Key]];
        if (j < min)
        {
            min = j;
        }
        int indexPlusWordLength = j + current.Key.Length;
        if (indexPlusWordLength > max)
        {
            max = indexPlusWordLength;
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate it if someone could point out where did I go wrong in my algorithm. Moreover, I kinda feel this is a very naive implementation. Maybe there is a better approach to solve this problem than trying to try out combinations of indexes?

Thanks!

Comment: Your algorithm is very complicated.  The code should be fairly simple. 1) Split string around spaces.  2) Start at word one until all four criteria are found.  Save results 3) Start at Word two until all found criteria are found.  If new length is shorter than first length replace old results with new results.  4) Repeat at word 3, then word 4, then word 5.

Comment: Yes, I understand my algorithm is very complicated. That's one of the reasons why I asked here: I want to see a different approach of solving this problem. I will try the method you've described, but be aware that the same search criteria might be within the source string multiple times, did you think about that in your proposed solution?

Comment: Also, is it possible that the search criteria would have a space in it? i.e. `{ "hello there", "foo", "bar" };`

Comment: Do the items found have to be in the same order in the source string as they are found in the criteria list? i.e. if you have `{"one", "two", "three"}` for your criteria, and your string is `"two three one two five three"`, would the correct response be `"two three one"` or `"one two five three"`?

Comment: @RufusL Yes actually, the search criteria could have a space in it. And the order of the search items does not matter as long as they are all found in the sub-string.

Answer (score 2):

This is a much simpler algorithm that will give you the shortest substring.

```
void Main()
{
    String source = "aaa wwwww fgffsd ththththt sss ww sgsgsgsghs bfbfb hhh sdfg kkk " +
        "dhdhtrherhrhrthrthrt ddfhdetehehe kkk wdwd aaa vcvc hhh zxzx sss ww nbnbn";
    List<String> criteria = new List<string> { "kkk", "aaa", "sss ww", "hhh" };
    var result = GetAllSubstringContainingCriteria(source, criteria)
        .OrderBy(sub => sub.Length).FirstOrDefault();
    // result is "kkk wdwd aaa vcvc hhh zxzx sss ww"
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetAllSubstringContainingCriteria(
    string source, List<string> criteria)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        var subString = source.Substring(i);
        if (criteria.Any(crit => subString.StartsWith(crit)))
        {
            var lastWordIndex = 
                GetLastCharacterIndexFromLastCriteriaInSubstring(subString, criteria);
            if (lastWordIndex >= 0)
                yield return string.Join(" ", subString.Substring(0, lastWordIndex));
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
}

private int GetLastCharacterIndexFromLastCriteriaInSubstring(
    string subString, List<string> criteria)
{
    var results = criteria.Select(crit => new { 
            index = subString.IndexOf(crit),
            criteria = crit});

    return results.All(result => result.index >= 0)
        ? results.Select(result => result.index + result.criteria.Length).Max()
        : -1;
}
```

Comment: Reading your solution, it seems to expect that the words have to be in the same order as listed in the 'criteria' list? I don't think that was listed as a requirement.

Comment: You are half right, my algorithm was wrong in the way it was expecting the first criteria to be the first word.  I have now fixed that mistake.

Comment: @KiNeTiC This actually worked. Only problem is that it assumes there are no spaces in the search items, which is not correct but I did not specify that as part of the initial requirements (my bad). So +1 for the working solution, but if you can modify your answer to take that additional requirement into consideration. I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer.  The algorithm is pretty much the same except for the fact I'm no longer splitting the source into a word list..

Answer (score 0):

Let the Java built-in classes do the work.  How about converting your criteria to a regular expression Pattern.  If the criteria are X or Y or Z . . ., convert this into a regular expression of the form "(X)|(Y)|(Z)|...", compile it, and execute it against the source string.

This, of course, returns the leftmost match.  You could code a very straightforward loop that iterates across all occurrences, caches them, and chooses the shortest--or the leftmost shortest--or, if two or more are equally short, then all of those.

Comment: A code example would help you get some points for this answer. Also, this is C#, not Java. :)